# VBA - Excel - Need a code to return a range of values based on a calendar

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to return the exact days a shift employee has to work based on a calendar (the complete calendar goes till the last day of the month):

```
  ID  | Days | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
 -----|------|-------------------
    1 |   30 | Y Y Y Y     Y Y
```

The days he works will always be pointed with a "Y".

**In this case, I'd like to send an e-mail to him:**

-You have to work from 1 to 4 
-You have to work from 7 to 8

I have already coded the sending e-mail sub, I only need the piece of code to select the days that have to be worked.

Comment: You should give us information about how is stored the data in the database. In your sample seems that the numbers are the column names, but you cannot give a number as a column name. So, we need to know that to help you, and also the database system (SQL Server, MySQL, etc)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: The information is stored in Excel. I have tried trying to hlookup for the values on the first row, but I can't define where to start and where to end. All I can do I list the values separated by comma, e.g. 1,2,3,4,7,8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution on my own on a very complicated way but it works:

1) One Sub for transposing the first row based on "Y" value
2) Add another Sub for adding an "if" formula to identify a line break when the range skips +1
3) Add another Sub for copying first and last value of each segment (divided by the break line)